# Emulating an XBox 360 controller from (not for, from) a laptop

Tags: c#, controller, emulation, xbox360

I want to create a C# program which can control an XBox 360 like you would with a controller, except from a program on* my laptop. However, every time I try to find anything pertaining to this on Google, I only get an endless flood of questions asking how to connect a 360 controller to a laptop, which is more or less the exact opposite of what I want.

Does anyone know a way to do what I want or am I just going to have to bang my head against an insurmountable wall for two days before then giving up?

Comment: I think this is probably a bigger task than you expected. The 360 just uses a USB port to receive input. The two gaps to fill are: 1) How do I send data from my laptop to that USB port? 2) What data do I send? Answering (1) will require you to do research on embedded devices, but is popular enough that you could probably find a decent number of guides. For (2) there is an overview of the Microsoft APIs for input devices here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput (it also links to the documentation). It'll probably be hard to find tutorials, but the information seems to be mostly there.

Comment: Extra things I realized: You probably don't need a special embedded device to send data into the 360's USB input port... just a cable. But a major hurdle I realized is that you need some app on the 360 to actually accept your input. I don't think the 360 will let you run arbitrary apps on it unless you pay for a developer's kit. I'm not sure of a workaround for this...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a development console and the SDK I could help you out, the task is essentially impossible with a retail console and your laptop or xbox would require some hardware modifications to work properly, unless you want to connect via a USB. It might be more plausible then. Regardless, if you have access to the proper software I might be able to lend you a hand.